# How to implement Akka HTTP Request Post Client Headers Authorization

Tags: scala, http, akka, akka-http

I'am trying to implement Akka http client for post request where Authorization will be given in header from postman. I am not able to authorize, following is my code

```
 def main(args: Array[String]) {

    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor = system.dispatcher
    val requestHeader = scala.collection.immutable.Seq(RawHeader("Authorization", "admin"))

    val requestHandler: HttpRequest => HttpResponse = {

      case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/GetTrackerData"), requestHeader, entity, _) =>
        val chunk = Unmarshal(entity).to[DeviceLocationData]

        val deviceLocationData = Await.result(chunk, 1.second)

        val responseArray = "Authorized"
        HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, responseArray)
        )

      case r: HttpRequest =>
        println(r.uri.toString())
        r.discardEntityBytes() // important to drain incoming HTTP Entity stream
        HttpResponse(404, entity = "Unknown resource!")
    }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandleSync(requestHandler, "0.0.0.0", 7070)
    println(s"iot engine api live at 0.0.0.0:7070")
    sys.addShutdownHook({
      println("ShutdownHook called")
      bindingFuture
        .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
        .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done
    })

  }
```

Whatever value I give from postman. It serves the request. What I am skipping ?

My use case is that result showed be displayed only after authorization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pattern matching on `HttpRequest`.

The `requestHeader` you use there is not the one you specified earlier but will be the *headers* from the HttpRequest itself.

One way to resolve it could be checking for the values in the headers:

```
case HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, Uri.Path("/GetTrackerData"), headers, entity, _) 
  if (headers.exists(h => h.name == "Authorization" && h.value ==  "admin"))  =>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one problem:

```
  case HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/GetTrackerData"), requestHeader, entity, _) =>
```

This does not match the current value of `requestHeader`, it creates a new value `requestHeader` containing the current headers of the `HttpRequest`. So this match will not check the `Authorization` field of the header. You will have to do this manually.

More generally, it would be worth looking at the `Route` support in Akka HTTP as a cleaner and more powerful way of implementing a server.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the help. Understood the problem and fixed the same.